# How to disable lightweight checkout on jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins

As for as I understood the `Lightweight Checkout` is enabled by default on Jenkins. Does someone know how to disable it?

How found the pieces of information below"

```
About Multibranch Pipeline support
Multibranch Pipelines support lightweight checkout since JENKINS-33273.
It is activated by default.
There is a kill switch to deactivate it.
Simply add org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.USE_HEAVYWEIGHT_CHECKOUT=true to Jenkins arguments
```

But I don't know how to add to Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudbees addressed [JENKINS-33273](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273) - Optimize Jenkinsfile loading and branch detection, which introduced/changed the behaviour.

Their blog has a post, [Why is my multibranch project cloning the whole repository on the master?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002991272-Why-is-my-multibranch-project-cloning-the-whole-repository-on-the-master-) and a link for [How to add Java arguments to Jenkins?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698).

See also [Jenkins Features Controlled with System Properties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/). Essentially, it's a parameter in the arguments to launch Jenkins itself. Make sure it's a `JENKINS_ARGS` and not `JAVA_OPTIONS`.

[JENKINS-45686](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45686) is Open to provide a UI option to manage this configurationy other means.

Additional pipeline info: [Pipeline-as-code with Multibranch Workflows in Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/)

Answer (score 0):

```
pipelineJob("pipeline with branch parameter") {
        stringParam {
            name('BRANCH')
            defaultValue('master')
            description('Branch name')
            trim(true)
        }
    }
    definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        github("username/myrepo", "https")
                        credentials("jenkins-gh")
                    }
                    branch("*/\${BRANCH}")
                }
            }
            scriptPath("jenkins/file/path")
            lightweight(lightweight=false)
        }
    }
    disabled(false)
}
```

more options: [here](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.WorkflowDefinitionContext.cpsScm)